# Помогите разобраться

Tags: php, битрикс

Всем, привет. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с корзиной, а именно с изменением количества товара через инпут. Вроде все делаю правильно, а изменение количества не происходит.

Вот сам код:

```html
<?
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php'); 
    CModule::IncludeModule("iblock");//Подключаю Инфоблоки
    CModule::IncludeModule("catalog"); //Подключаю Каталог
    CModule::IncludeModule("sale"); //Подключаю Продажи
    CModule::IncludeModule('highloadblock');// Подключаю High-Блоки
    $date_now = date("d.m.Y H:i:s");//Текущее время
    $postDeleteItemID = $_POST["deleteItemID"];//Удаление товара из корзины
    $editPlusItemID = $_POST["editPlusItemID"];//Увеличение количество товара в корзине
    $editMinusItemID = $_POST["editMinusItemID"]; //Уменьшение количество товара в корзине
    $changeItemID = $_POST["changeItemID"];//Переменная Изменение количества товара в корзине через инпут
    $quanityItem = $_POST["QUANTITY"];//Переменная количества товара
    $createBasket = $_POST["createBasket"];//Переменная создания букета
    $idSelectArray = $_POST["bouquet_item"];
    $current_page = $_POST["current_page"];
    $item_id = $_POST["item_id"];
    $WishId = $_POST["wishId"];
    if(isset($_POST["count_item"]))$count_item = $_POST["count_item"]; else $count_item = 1;
    if(isset($item_id)){
        Add2BasketByProductID($item_id,$count_item,array());
    }
    if($editPlusItemID || $editMinusItemID || $postDeleteItemID || $item_id) $opener_active = "active"; else  $opener_active = "";
    //Удаление элемента при клике на крестик
    if(isset($postDeleteItemID) && $postDeleteItemID != ""){
        CSaleBasket::Delete($postDeleteItemID);
    }

    //Увеличение количество товара в корзине
    if(isset($editPlusItemID) && $editPlusItemID != ""){
        $arFields = array(
           "QUANTITY" => $quanityItem,
        );
        CSaleBasket::Update($editPlusItemID, $arFields);
    }
    //Уменьшение количество товара в корзине
    if(isset($editMinusItemID) && $editMinusItemID != ""){
        $arFields = array(
           "QUANTITY" => $quanityItem,
        );
        CSaleBasket::Update($editMinusItemID, $arFields);
    }

    //Изменение количества товара в корзине через инпут
    if(isset($changeItemID) && $changeItemID != ""){
        $arFields = array(
           "QUANTITY" => $quanityItem,
        );
        CSaleBasket::Update($changeItemID, $arFields);
    }

    // Выведем актуальную корзину для текущего пользователя
    $arBasketItems = array();
    $dbBasketItems = CSaleBasket::GetList(
            array(
                    "NAME" => "ASC",
                    "ID" => "ASC"
                ),
            array(
                    "FUSER_ID" => CSaleBasket::GetBasketUserID(),
                    "LID" => SITE_ID,
                    "ORDER_ID" => "NULL",
                    "DELAY" => "N"
                ),
            false,
            false,
            array("ID","PRODUCT_ID","PRODUCT_PRICE_ID","NAME","PRICE","CURRENCY","QUANTITY","BASE_PRICE")
        );
    $CountItemBasket =  CSaleBasket::GetList(false, array("FUSER_ID" => CSaleBasket::GetBasketUserID(),"LID" => SITE_ID,"ORDER_ID" => "NULL","DELAY" => "N"),false,false,array("ID" ))->SelectedRowsCount();
    if($CountItemBasket == 0) $empty = "block"; else $empty = "none";
    ?>


  <div class="header">
    <a class="basket-opener" title="Корзина" onclick="BasketOpener();">
      <div class="icon">
        <div class="text">
          <div class="uni-aligner-vertical"></div>
          <div class="text_number">
            <?=$CountItemBasket?>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="sections <?=$opener_active?>">
    <div class="section product_section" id="product-section" style="display: block;">
      <div id="basket-root" class="bx-basket bx-green bx-step-opacity" style="opacity: 1;">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="mb-3 basket-items-list-wrapper basket-items-list-wrapper-height-fixed basket-items-list-wrapper-light" id="basket-items-list-wrapper">
              <div class="basket-items-list-container" id="basket-items-list-container" style="min-height: 0px;">
                <div class="basket-items-list-overlay" id="basket-items-list-overlay" style="display: none;"></div>
                <div class="basket-items-list" id="basket-item-list" style="height: 300px; overflow-y: auto;">
                  <div class="basket-search-not-found" id="basket-item-list-empty-result" style="display: <?=$empty?>;">
                    <div class="basket-search-not-found-icon"></div>
                    <div class="basket-search-not-found-text">Корзина пуста</div>
                  </div>
                  <table class="basket-items-list-table" id="basket-item-table">
                    <tbody>
                      <?$count=0;?>
                        <?while ($arItems = $dbBasketItems->Fetch()){
  //Выбор товара из инфоблока
  $objectItem = Array("IBLOCK_ID", "ID", "NAME", "PREVIEW_PICTURE", "IBLOCK_SECTION_ID","DETAIL_PAGE_URL", "PROPERTY_6", "PROPERTY_7", "PROPERTY_8", "PROPERTY_97");
  $objectOrder = Array("ID"=>"ASC");//Сортировка
  $objectFilter = Array(
   "ID" => $arItems["PRODUCT_ID"]
  );//Фильтр
  $objectSelectArray = CIBlockElement::GetList($objectOrder, $objectFilter, false, Array(), $objectItem);
  $item_properties = "";
  while($obSelectObject  = $objectSelectArray ->GetNextElement()){

   $objectFields = $obSelectObject ->GetFields();
   $objectProperties  = $obSelectObject ->GetProperties();
   //Вывод картинки
   $item_image = CFile::GetPath($objectFields["PREVIEW_PICTURE"]);
   //Вывод цены товара, учитываю количество этого товара
   $priceAllItem = $arItems["PRICE"]*$arItems["QUANTITY"];
   $totalPriceBasket = $totalPriceBasket + $priceAllItem;
  
   $priceAllItemDiscount = $arItems["BASE_PRICE"]*$arItems["QUANTITY"];
   $totalPriceBasketDiscount = $totalPriceBasketDiscount + $priceAllItemDiscount;
   $discountPrice = $totalPriceBasket - $totalPriceBasketDiscount;
   if($objectFields["PROPERTY_6_VALUE"] == 'да') $new = "Y"; else $new = "N";
   if($objectFields["PROPERTY_7_VALUE"] == 'да') $hit = "Y"; else $hit = "N";
   if($objectFields["PROPERTY_8_VALUE"] == 'да') $stock = "Y"; else $stock = "N";
 ?>

                          <tr class="basket-items-list-item-container" id="basket-item-<?=$arItems[" ID "]?>" data-entity="basket-item" data-id="<?=$arItems[" ID "]?>">
                            <td class="basket-items-list-item-descriptions">
                              <div class="basket-items-list-item-descriptions-inner" id="basket-item-height-aligner-<?=$arItems[" ID "]?>">
                                <div class="basket-item-block-image">
                                  <a href="<?=$objectFields[" DETAIL_PAGE_URL "]?>" class="basket-item-image-link">
                                    <?if($item_image){?>
                                      <img class="basket-item-image" alt="<?=$objectFields[" NAME "]?>" src="<?=$item_image?>">
                                      <?}else{?>
                                        <div class="empty-image-block"></div>
                                        <?}?>
                                  </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="basket-item-block-info">
                                  <span class="basket-item-actions-remove d-block d-md-none" data-entity="basket-item-delete"></span>
                                  <h2 class="basket-item-info-name">
                                    <a href="<?=$objectFields[" DETAIL_PAGE_URL "]?>" class="basket-item-info-name-link">
                                      <span data-entity="basket-item-name"><?=$objectFields["NAME"]?></span>
                                    </a>
                                  </h2>
                                  <div class="basket-item-block-properties"></div>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="basket-items-list-item-price basket-items-list-item-price-for-one">
                              <div class="basket-item-block-price d-none d-sm-block">
                                <div class="basket-item-price-current">
                                  <span class="basket-item-price-current-text" id="basket-item-price-<?=$arItems[" ID "]?>"><?=CurrencyFormat($arItems["PRICE"], "RUB")?></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="basket-item-price-title">цена за 1
                                  <?if($objectFields["PROPERTY_97_VALUE"] === 'пар') { ?>пару
                                    <?}else{?>
                                      <?=$objectFields["PROPERTY_97_VALUE"];?>
                                        <?}?>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="basket-items-list-item-amount">
                              <div class="basket-item-block-amount" data-entity="basket-item-quantity-block">
                                <span class="basket-item-amount-btn-minus" data-entity="basket-item-quantity-minus" onclick="editMinusItemBasket(<?=$arItems[" ID "]?>,<?=$arItems['QUANTITY']?>)"></span>
                                <div class="basket-item-amount-filed-block">
                                  <input type="text" class="basket-item-amount-filed" value="<?=$arItems['QUANTITY']?>" data-value="<?=$arItems['QUANTITY']?>" data-entity="basket-item-quantity-field" id="basket-item-quantity-<?=$arItems[" ID "]?>">
                                </div>
                                <span class="basket-item-amount-btn-plus" data-entity="basket-item-quantity-plus" onclick="editPlusItemBasket(<?=$arItems[" ID "]?>,<?=$arItems['QUANTITY']?>)"></span>
                                <div class="basket-item-amount-field-description">
                                  <?=$objectFields["PROPERTY_97_VALUE"];?>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="basket-items-list-item-price">
                              <div class="basket-item-block-price">
                                <div class="basket-item-price-current">
                                  <span class="basket-item-price-current-text" id="basket-item-sum-price-<?=$arItems[" ID "]?>"><?=CurrencyFormat($priceAllItem, "RUB")?></span>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="basket-items-list-item-remove d-none d-md-block">
                              <div class="basket-item-block-actions">
                                <span class="basket-item-actions-remove" onclick="ajax_basket_delete_item(<?=$arItems[" ID "]?>);"></span>
                              </div>
                            </td>
                          </tr>
                          <?}}?>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <script>
          $(document).ready(function() {
            var BasketItems = $('.basket-small-fly .text_number').text(),
              BasketCost = $('.basket-small-fly .basket-coupon-block-total-price-current').text();
            $('#win8_wrapper').hide()
            $('.dropdown-block').click(function() {
              if ($('.dropdown-list', this).hasClass('active')) {
                $('i', this).removeClass('fa-caret-up').addClass('fa-caret-down');
                $('.dropdown-list', this).slideUp(0);
                $('.dropdown-list', this).removeClass('active');
              } else {
                $('i', this).removeClass('fa-caret-down').addClass('fa-caret-up');
                $('.dropdown-list', this).slideDown(300);
                $('.dropdown-list', this).addClass('active');
              }
            });
            $('.dropdown-list li').click(function() {
              var count_item = $('.count-item', this).text();
              $('li.selected .count-item').text(count_item);
              var item_id = $(this).closest('.item-block').attr('data-id');
              changeItemBasket(item_id, count_item);

            });
          });
        </script>
```

Comment: Не ясно, где в шаблоне выводится "changeItemID", как он заполняется. Вы уверены, что в $_POST приходят все, данные, которые вам нужны?

Comment: День добрый. Постарайтесь сократить код, чтоб предоставить [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: может нет больше на складе товара (если настроено такое)